# How to get "Did you mean" data from Google without api in c?

Tags: c, curl, google-search

I try to download the source code of the Google search page with curl in C and get "did you mean" or "showing results for" data but I fail.

How can I save the Google search page source code using only C?

sample url: https://www.google.com/search?q=stacoverflow

i want: view-source:https://www.google.com/search?q=stacoverflow

Thank you.

Comment: By using the whole bunch of network programming stuff. Too broad.

Comment: What makes you think Google will let you have their source code? Try looking at the code in your browser.

Comment: Your code will fail due to Google Human Verification Protection.

Comment: Without _any_ API?... With plain sockets, and by implementing (understanding) an HTTP client... actually Google probably won't respond to just HTTP, so you'll need to re-implement SSL too... enjoy!

Comment: What have you tried? What went wrong? Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I want to normalize the space-free text and I have limited time for it. Google is doing very well. e.g. lordoftherings ->lord of the rings.  Do you have any idea for this job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: make sure you specified user agent. (Search curl docs to find out how to do this.) Google doesn't give you page if you didn't specified user agent.

This is my user agent and it seems to work: "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.119 Safari/537.36"

Second: make sure you are trying to find RIGHT string in the output of Google site. Google may try to figure out your country from your IP address and try to localize string "did you mean" or "Showing results for" for your language. For example, I am in Estonia now, Google (I tried to access google.COM!) determined my current country and gave me "Näitab tulemusi" instead of "Showing results for". Also, I want to point here: your curl library doesn't share settings, coockies, etc with your browser. I. e. if you set up some language in Google in browser, curl will not inherit it.

And third: when I get Google results in English, I get "Showing results for" instead of "Did you mean". So, try to search for different strings.

Try to pass Google output through some HTML prettyfier and look at resulting source